# How do I apply a texture in Blender Render without it being influenced by the object it's applied to?

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine

Ok, I'm not sure if I'm even asking the question correctly, and what I'm trying to do might be a bit on the weird side.  So, I'll try to explain what I want to do, without sounding like a madman.

I have an image, shown below:

[image]

Now, I know how to apply the texture in the usual way.  Getting it to look like this is easy:

[image]

What I want to do though, is this:

[image]

I can achieve that effect in the compositor simply enough, but I want to avoid using the compositor if at all possible.  I was wondering if there was a way to do this with BI?

The reason I'm trying to do something so silly, is that I am primarily a pixel-artist, and I've been experimenting with trying to generate decent-looking pixel art via Blender.  Once I'm able to do the above, I can then produce something like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any advice or nudges in the right direction!

Comment: What render engine are you using? Use *Screen* or *Window* space texture coordinates

Comment: Blender Internal.  I'm not entirely sure how I would use Window texture coords in the node editor?  Or do I not need to?

Answer (score 6):

Its quite easy, just pick the "Window" coordinate in the texture panel under "Mapping"

[image]

One bit of advice though is that during animation, when you move the object or camera, the texture will move with it. i.e. your "pixels" wont stay in the same spot, so you will potentially have a flicker in your "dithering".

For stills though this is totally fine.

Comment: I've tried this method previously, but it's not quite what I need.  The shading on the object is still visible.  I need to be able to completely eliminate everything, basically having the object act as a mask of sorts.  That is, of course, unless I'm missing something in the settings, and doing this will actually get me what I need to do.  I've tried it though, but I'm not yet a Blender expert, so I might indeed have overlooked some crucial step.

Comment: Sounds like you need a tutorial for a custom shader and its not really an issue of the texture coordinate. But you're in luck since I did something similar with my ink shader like 7 years back: http://matrep.parastudios.de/index.php?action=view&material=793-inked-sketch
Download that shader and try to replace the noise textures with your pixel grid and play around with the color ramp, it should give you the effect you need. Its based on using the color ramp as a contrast control for light input. So your shadow is mixed with the pixel grid. (no nodes)

Comment: Alternatively make a new question and I/we will try and guide you through the process of making your own.

Answer (score 2):

In Cycles you would use the Texture Coordinates Node:
[image]

You would use the Window output from this one to get the results you want

Comment: With Cycles, it would indeed be easier to just use that node.  My problem with Cycles though, is that it really is more geared towards photorealism and the sort, and there's really too much tweaking involved in order to get the simple NPR style that I'm looking for.